# Multi-window support and Flutter App Development

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-layout

How can i enable my flutter app to be used in Multi-Window ??

[image]

Comment: Is it not working out of the box? I would've guessed that it would be turned on unless explicitly declared off using `android:resizeableActivity="false"`.

Comment: how to add this in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to enable it. I works automatically. These two Apps on the Screenshot are Flutter Apps.
[image: Flutter Apps sharing the screen]

Comment: doesn't work on a samsung tab 4 7", it depends on the device ?

Comment: Maybe your phone doesn't support this function. Have you tried it with a different phone? Maybe 4.7" is too small.